# Calling an executable from within Fortran Code

Tags: fortran

I am writing a Fortran code called code.f. I would like this code to run another executable which I can store in the same directory as the code (or as code.f when it is compiled).

Is it acceptable coding to do this using:

```
    CALL system(./executable < input.inp > output.out)
```

Or is this obviously bad practice?

**************ALTERNATIVELY**************

I have the code for the executable, exec.f. Should this be compiled with code.f and linked using the code.f make file, could you possibly advise how to do this, the current make file looks like:

```
    FFLAGS = $(MYFLGS) -I$(INCDIR) -static
    OBJ =   file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o
    ...
    ...
    Code:        code.f code.o $(OBJ) par.h
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -o $@ code.o $(OBJ) $(LIBS)
```

Would it be correct to just update

```
   OBJ = file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o exec.f
```

And after putting in this like how would the code in exec.f be called from within code.f?

Please tell me if I need to make my question clearer. Thank you very much for your help

James

Comment: This is extremely subjective. It is a normal practice, but we cannot know if it is the right thing for your problem, because we don't know anything about it.

Comment: the main issue you need to deal with is the directory the system command is executed in may not be the directory where the executable lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SYSTEM](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM.html) function would not be present at all if it **always** was a bad practise to use it.

To the second question: You cannot just join two executables to one executable, because it can contain only one entry-point (Main program or `PROGRAM`).

To sum you options:

1. Change `PROGRAM` in `exec.f` to `SUBROUTINE` and create a library from `exec.f`. Link together and call the library function from `Code`
2. Change `PROGRAM` in `exec.f` to `SUBROUTINE` and add `exec.f` to `Code` objectives. Call the `exec.f` function from `Code`
3. use `SYSTEM` call from `Code`

All options are valid and have different use-cases.

Comment: Thank you, I have used option 2

Answer (score 1):

Acceptable is an opinion question.  I would try to avoid this approach but it might be the best solution to some problems.

Fortran 2008 provides the intrinsic procedure `execute_command_line` which will be more standard than "system".